# Serialization with implemenation

Tags: java, serialization

Hey so I'm new to using serialization, at least the way that our professor wants us to. I have the issue that for some reason it will not serialize even with java.io.Serializable implemented. I tried the direct path and "Serializable" neither work. Im not sure whats going wrong or why, as far as I understand there should not be any methods that I need to implement, correct?

THE ERROR I GET

```
java.io.NotSerializableException: Transaction
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1185)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:349)
    at TransactionManager.serialize(TransactionManager.java:81)
    at Test3.main(Test3.java:62)
java.io.WriteAbortedException: writing aborted; java.io.NotSerializableException: Transaction
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1598)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:430)
    at TransactionManager.deSerialize(TransactionManager.java:96)
    at Test3.main(Test3.java:67)
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: Transaction
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1185)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:349)
    at TransactionManager.serialize(TransactionManager.java:81)
    at Test3.main(Test3.java:62)
```

THE CODE

```
import java.awt.print.Book;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;

public class TransactionManager implements Serializable {

    private ArrayList<Transaction> col;

    public TransactionManager() {
        col = new ArrayList<Transaction>();
    }

    public void add(Transaction obj) {
        col.add(obj);
    }

    public void clear() {
        col.clear();
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return col.size();
    }

    public ArrayList<Transaction> getAll() {
        ArrayList<Transaction> temp = col;
        Collections.sort(temp, new Comparator<Transaction>() {
            public int compare(Transaction s1, Transaction s2) {
                return ((Integer) s1.getId()).compareTo(s2.getId());
            }
        });
        return temp;
    }

    public ArrayList<Transaction> findBuyer(String name) {
        ArrayList<Transaction> temp = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < col.size(); i++) {
            if (col.get(i).getBuyer().equals(name)) {
                temp.add(col.get(i));
            }
        }
        Collections.sort(temp, new Comparator<Transaction>() {
            public int compare(Transaction s1, Transaction s2) {
                return ((Integer) s1.getId()).compareTo(s2.getId());
            }
        });
        return temp;
    }

    public ArrayList<Transaction> findSeller(String name) {
        ArrayList<Transaction> temp = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < col.size(); i++) {
            if (col.get(i).getSeller().equals(name)) {
                temp.add(col.get(i));
            }
        }
        Collections.sort(temp, new Comparator<Transaction>() {
            public int compare(Transaction s1, Transaction s2) {
                return ((Integer) s1.getId()).compareTo(s2.getId());
            }
        });
        return temp;
    }

    public Transaction findId(int ID) {
        for (int i = 0; i < col.size(); i++) {
            if (col.get(i).getId() == ID) {
                return col.get(i);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void serialize() throws IOException {
        FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(new File("savePerson.ser"));
        ObjectOutputStream outputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(output);
        for (int i = 0; i < col.size(); i++) {
            outputStream.writeObject(col.get(i));
        }
        output.close();
        outputStream.close();
    }

    public void deSerialize() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {

        FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File("savePerson.ser"));
        boolean cont = true;
        try {
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(inputStream);
            while (cont) {
                Transaction obj = null;
                try {
                    obj = (Transaction) ois.readObject();
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                if (obj != null)
                    col.add(obj);
                else
                    cont = false;
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            inputStream.close();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: you have to implement `Serializable` on `Transaction` also

Comment: Adding `Serializable` to `TransactionManager` doesn't make the `Transaction` class serializable. The error message specifically says it's a problem with `Transaction`, not with `TransactionManager`. When something fails, it's always best to start your research of the problem by reading the error message *in detail*.

Comment: @Deadpool Thank you that helps, do you know what it means to have an EOFException? it occurs with Deserialization

Comment: If doesn't make sense to serialize transactions. They are very temporary things and not for example resumable. `EOFException` means you tried to read past the end of stream, just as it says in the documentation.